# Adding own component to Modal Antd design

Tags: javascript, java, reactjs, antd

Is it possible to add my own Select to the Modal ?

Just an example of what i mean by Select:

```
  <div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is my function with the Modal properties

```
showConfirm = (e, title, content, submit, cancel) => {
    const onChange = this.onRadioButtonChange;
    if (e.target.value === 2) {
        confirm({
            okText: submit,
            cancelText: cancel,
            width: '600px',
            title,
            content,
            onOk() {
                onChange(e);
            },
            onCancel() {
            }
        });
    } else {
        onChange(e);
    }
};
```

I use that function inside a radio group with including translation

```
 <Radio.Group style={{marginTop: '15px'}}
                             onChange={e => this.showConfirm(e, t('preferenceConfirmTitle'), t('preferenceConfirmContent'), t('submit'), t('cancel'))}
```

Comment: Please post some code that you have tried for adding the select

Comment: Of course, it is possible. I don't recommend it since antd already has a Select component that you could customize to your specific needs. Why exactly does antd Select component not work for you?

Comment: @JayCodist indeed there is a select component but i cannot see a property of antd Modal that would accept own component or antd component select

Comment: I don't understand that. What do you mean by own component? Or you want the Select to be a child of the Modal?

Comment: @JayCodist correct

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question well, the Popconfirm modal (or Modal.confirm) component is not intended for that type of usage, you have the Modal component for that. According to the antd docs:

> The difference with the confirm modal dialog is that it's more lightweight than the static popped full-screen modal.

If you want more controls/customization on your modal than Popconfirm's "OK" and "Cancel", etc, you should use the Modal component that supports all kind of content/children.
Then you'll simply have to do:

```
<Modal>
   <Select>
   ...
   </Select>
   ...
</Modal>
```